# Circuit breaker selection that can be tripped with a microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, microchip, fault, circuit-analysis

I am designing a system that will simulate an upstream fault with a micro-controller action. the micro-controller will send a signal to a circuit breaker to simulate a line to ground fault(just like the test button on several circuit breakers). What kind of circuit breaker can i select that can be electronically actuated by a micro-controllers digital i/o pins. Or what technique can i use to simulate this fault.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to simulate some ground leakage for a [GFI/RCD device](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residual-current_device), then a standard mains rated relay with resistor in series should do. The relay coil can be driven from ta microcontroller output + transistor (or directly if the coil current/voltage is low enough) The typical threshold is around 5-30mA according to the link. So if your line voltage is e.g 115V, you should guarantee a trip with 50mA.

Then a 115V / 0.050A = 2.3kΩ. A beefy resistor would be required, as you are looking at 115V * 0.05A = 5.75W. You could either use a 10W 2.3kΩ resistor, or use e.g. 4 * 2.5W 10k resistors in parallel (for 46mA)

Alternatively, use a ready made solenoid voltmeter, which (according to the above link) are apparently used for testing RCDs quite commonly due to their relatively high current draw. This would have to be used manually though.

Comment: Thanks alot. What if i wanted to simulate an overcurrent or overload. What technique and breaker selection would i need.

Answer (score 0):

You can buy breakers with a 'shunt trip coil' fitted that can be tripped electronically (Usually applying a pulse of power to the shunt trip coil will trip the breaker, adding the micro should be obvious).

Note that tripping the breaker with a shunt trip coil is NOT the same as testing the breaker (especially for the overload and overcurrent case, as it does not in any sense mimic the effects of the actual cause of the breaker tripping on the surrounding circuitry, a real overload will cause thermal (and potentially mechanical force) effects on the surrounding wiring that you do not get with a shunt trip.

Turing off a breaker under processor control is easy, TESTING a breaker, especially at the outer parts of the performance envelope is hard, and often destructive, you could use a micro to control the firing of some kind of triggered gap to short the supply I suppose, but I am not sure I would want to be around such a thing.